# Where to put the DLL in C# source?

Tags: c#

I just built https://snowballstem.org 's C# port.

It makes a `dll` I can reference in my project

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Snowball">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\snowballstemmer.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

What's the best place to put that (and other such) dll so that my codebase remains well-structured and portable and other developers can join in development very easily after cloning it?

Comment: Generally we don't include 3rd party DLL's in our checkins to our source control repository. Instead, we consume 3rd party DLL's via a reference to a NuGet package. If this project doesn't have a published NuGet package at nuget.org, perhaps you can offer to help them by setting one up. Then your project would reference that NuGet package.

Comment: This is kinda opinion-based. But you can just put it in a separate folder relative to your solution, e.g. `lib` and for each external lib which can't be found on Nuget, make a new subfolder in that `lib` and just reference them directly. Just make sure to include this `lib` folder in your source control so every team member has it in the same path relative to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by mason, for .NET project it recommended to references to NuGet packages. However if you, for some reason, need / like to keep the libraries you use in a repository, you can use a file structure like this:

1 YourSolutionName

1.1 src // sources

1.1.1 project 1

etc.

1.2 libs // libraries / dlls you reference

1.2.1 library1

etc.

1.3 docs // documentation

etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is true, we really don't want to have dll references in our code repo, if possible. However, if the target project does not have a NuGet package then it's not really possible.

Assuming you have a project folder and a solution file outside of it, I would create another folder, called something like ThirdPartyDlls and chuck in  there. You can then add a reference to it in your project, making sure you use a relative path to it. This can be changed in the project file if necessary.

If you use Git for your source control, you can force push dlls.
Now, I am not a fan of this method, but sometimes you just don't have an option.

Comment: Would you put `ThirdPartyDlls` into or outside of the project folder.. and why?

Comment: Inside. So if the project is moved, the relative path is still valid.

Comment: it can be outside as well. the relative path would be something like ..\ThirdPartyDlls\whatever.dll